# What's the proper usage of the word "legion" in terms of a large, indefinite number?

Tags: word-usage

The usage of the word "legion" sometimes sounds awkward to me.

E.g.,

> His fans are **legion**.

To make it make sense, I replaced the word with "numerous", but it's still a "false friend" in that it seems to imply (to me) that they are "legendary."

In other cases, I'm unsure how to use it.

E.g.,

Does "the library was sparse except for legions of the Herald" or "legions of books" make sense?

Can someone give some various examples of the word's usage in terms or quantity?

Comment: We don't often use that word in everyday speech or writing. Note there is no connection beween 'legion' and 'legend'. I would say 'stacks' of books - a 'legion' is a group of people. You can find example usages of the adjective 'legion' in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/legion).

Comment: Not to mention the Biblical 'My name is Legion', explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_in_popular_culture#:~:text=10%20References-,Background,%2C%20for%20we%20are%20many.%22)

Comment: if you are unsure how to use it, don't. It is archaic or poetic, and to use it with a modern word like "fans" is incongruous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> His fans are legion.

**legion (adjective)** = numerous, many, countless.

OED

> B. *adj.a. In attributive use.*

2008   G. Haigh Inside Out v. 203   *There are legion stories of McGilvray's liberal out-of-hours hospitality.*

> *b. In predicative use.*
>
> 2014   C. Cobb et al. Chem. of Alchemy v. 89   *The equipment designed by alchemists to perform this operation was legion and elaborate.*

**legion (noun)**

> *Roman History.* **A body of infantry in the Roman army, ranging in number from 3,000 to 6,000 (at the time of Marius), and usually combined with many cavalry.**

and by extension

> **b. An armed host; (a part of) an army.**
>
> 1972   Sunday Mirror 16 Apr. 23/3   *President Nixon has ordered his legions home.*

and by further extension:

> **2. A vast host or multitude (of persons or things).**
>
> 1908   Proc. Delaware County Inst. Sci. 3 122   *Sweet fern lost its charm, when, too late, alas! it was discovered to be the habitat of..legions of seed ticks.*
>
> 2014   Observer 23 Mar. 12/1   *The legions of middle-class women who now shop regularly at the so-called discounters.*

Comment: Worth adding that the Roman Legion was the **largest** military unit of the Roman Empire, which is how the word came to be associated with the concept of "many" or "countless".  A Roman Legion was a massive and terrifying force in the ancient age.

Answer (score 13):

The specific predicative usage "X is/are legion" in your original example comes from the Gospel account of Jesus exorcising a large number of demons from a possessed man and sending them into a nearby herd of swine. According to the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/legion_2):

> The adjective dates from the late 17th cent., in early use often in the phrase *my, their, etc. name is legion*, i.e. ‘we, they, etc. are many’ (Mark 5:9) in the Bible.

Here's the story from verses 6-9 in the King James Version (via [BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/kjv/mark/5.htm)), emphasis mine:

> But when he [the possessed man] saw Jesus afar off, he ran and worshipped him, and cried with a loud voice, and said, What have I to do with thee, Jesus, thou Son of the most high God? I adjure thee by God, that thou torment me not. For he said unto him, Come out of the man, thou unclean spirit. And he asked him, What is thy name? And he answered, saying, **My name is Legion: for we are many.**

The same story appears in [Luke 8](https://biblehub.com/kjv/luke/8.htm) and [Matthew 8](https://biblehub.com/kjv/matthew/8.htm), although Matthew doesn't mention the name and Luke doesn't include the iconic "we are many" line.

Comment: iconic or ironic?

Comment: @Michael I think it's an iconic line but I realized I might have meant it's iconic that Luke doesn't include it, I'll rephrase!

Comment: There's also an interesting step from using *Legion* as a name (i.e. proper noun) in the gospels, to using it as an adjective....

Answer (score 5):

The following [post](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/legion) can be helpful  about its usage:

> A legion is a horde or a large number of people or things. It was originally a term for a military unit.
>
> In Roman times, a legion was a large unit of men in the army, and the word is still used in many militaries.
>
> However, it also means a whole bunch of people doing anything. If
> someone has many fans, you can say legion of fans or legions of fans,
> but either way, that's a lot of fans. There are legions of stars in
> the sky. When you see legion, you can be sure there's an awful lot of
> something.

(Vocabulary.com)

Other [usage examples:](https://vocabularytoday.com/2021/03/07/legion-meaning-usage-quotes-and-social-examples/)

> 1. Roller skating never stopped being cool, but this year the sport has picked up legions of new fans.
> 2. Because the companies that Reddit’s legion of traders decided to pump were ultimately not selected for anything other than price plasticity.
> 3. All have been criticized for inflating the cost of living in big cities, particularly on the West Coast, where legions of well-paid software developers helped drive up housing prices.
> 4. The band’s legions of loyal fans—and some politicians—are calling for delays to BTS’s military service or the formation of an alternative option, like working abroad to represent South Korean interests.
> 5. The coronavirus pandemic has been a boon for digital payments, inspiring legions of people to buy more things online and to use contactless payments.

Comment: This post has been suddenly flagged as off-topic, but I do not see any comments pertaining to this post having any issues. It has been well received, awarded points, also for a popular post, and was even tweeted out by Stack Exchange. Can someone help me understand what's wrong with this post of how I might fix it?

Comment: @romebot there are multiple problems with the question. For a start, you didn't include any evidence of the research you'd done, such as quoting a dictionary definition or etymology. Secondly, your unfamiliarity with a word is an insufficient reason to ask here: EL&U is specifically for *linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts*, and your post is a bit too basic. The fact that some users rushed to answer your question rather than assess its suitability for our site says more about them than it does about the question itself.

Comment: @romebot "fixing" it is problematic, as people have already answered your original question, so a change to the question sufficient to warrant its reopening could easily invalidate those answers. I think it's fairer to leave it closed. A valid question on "legion" might relate to its transition from a highly specific usage as a proper noun to the more general usage as an adjective **but without the word changing its ending** – compared to, say, "Satan" becoming "Satanic" (similarly *Orwellian*, *Darwinian*, *Celtic*)...

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica thank you for clarifying. I didn't know that this was for linguists, etc. Is there a more appropriate forum for my question?

Comment: @romebot Not within Stack Exchange. Our other site [ell.se] is a better place for this kind of question (along the lines of "I'm not fluent in English, so I'm not sure how to use *legion*"), but they too require the question to demonstrate some evidence of research. Forums like Reddit and Quora have a much lower bar, so maybe you could ask there. Or find the answer yourself: look up several online dictionaries, to get a sense of the different takes on the word's usage. Try [Onelook](https://www.onelook.com/), which lists a range of dictionaries and their definitions for a given word. :-)